# How does bitwise 'or' becomes a '+=' in bytecode for python

Tags: python, bytecode, bitwise-or

I was reading the following explanation of python bytecode. I'm posting a lot in order to give the full context. I'm confused about the part where the bitwise 'or' becomes a '+='.

> ```
> EXTENDED_ARG 1
> CALL_FUNCTION 4
> ```
>
> When the interpreter executes EXTENDED_ARG, its oparg (which is 1) is
> left-shifted by eight bits and stored in a temporary variable. Let’s
> call it extended_arg (do not confuse it with the opname EXTENDED_ARG):
>
> ```
> extened_arg = 1 << 8  # same as 1 * 256
> ```
>
> So the binary value 0b1 (the binary value of 1) is converted to
> 0b100000000. This is like multiplying 1 by 256 in the decimal system
> and extened_arg will be equal to 256. Now we have two bytes in
> extened_arg. When the interpreter reaches to the next instruction,
> this two-byte value is added to its oparg (which is 4 here) using a
> bitwise or.
>
> ```
> extened_arg = extened_arg | 4
> # Same as extened_arg += 4
> ```
>
> This is like adding the value of the oparg to extened_arg. So now we
> have:
>
> ```
> extened_arg = 256 + 4 = 260
> ```
>
> and this value will be used as the actual oparg of CALL_FUNCTION. So,
> in fact,
>
> ```
> EXTENDED_ARG 1
> CALL_FUNCTION 4
> ```
>
> is interpreted as:
>
> ```
> EXTENDED_ARG 1
> CALL_FUNCTION 260
> ```

Can someone explain how this translates.

Comment: The bitwise-or of `4` and `256` happens to be equal to the sum of `4` and `256`, because they have no set bits in common. This has nothing to do with either Python or bytecode; it's a pure *mathematical* fact.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` and `y` share no set bits, then `x | y` is equivalent to `x + y`.

Comment: What does it mean to share a set bit?

Comment: @Joemoor94 `x << 8` (where *x* is 1 but whatever) and 4 do not have common bits because 4 is less than 256

Comment: @JoeyMoore: Line up the binary representations of the numbers (padded to the same length) and look for any columns where both have a 1. 1s in the binary representation are set bits.

Comment: @bruno I think this is highlighting a deeper ignorance on my part

Answer (score 1):

- step 1 : `1 << 8`
  this is equal to `100000000`.
   Which is `256` in decimal
- step 2: now `256 + 4 = 260`. (obviously)

   `256|4` is same as `100000000|100 = 100000100 = 260`. (check how bitwise operators work)

from the above 2 statements the author concluded that `+=` is same as `|`

note about `or` operator:

if you want to find the result of ORing to operands, just line them up, like you do when you add 2 numbers, then look at each pair of bits from right to left and if there is at least one `1` bit then the resulting number will have a `1` bit too, otherwise it is a `0`.

Comment: warning in the current conditions + is same as |, not += which is same as |=

Answer (score 0):

If one of the operands is known to be zero, then `0 + bit = bit` gives the same result as `0 | bit == bit`, where `bit` is `0` or `1`.